# Django Admin prevent delete on last record

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm new to django and learning as I go.

I have a model that must have 1 record, therefore I want to prevent delete for the last record.

model.py

```
class SliderContent (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image')
```

I tried the following in admin.py

```
class SliderContentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
.....
    def delete_model(self, request, obj):
     if last_record:
          storage = messages.get_messages(request)
          storage.used = True
          messages.error(request, 'Cannot delete last record.')
     else:
          obj.delete()
```

This didn't work, I have also looked at a pre_delete receiver but from what I have read this won't work as I'm using the build in Admin views.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Note that [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods) say that the `delete_model` method must delete the object, and is not for veto purposes.

Comment: Where is ```last_record``` defined? Try to use ```count()``` to check if there it's the last record

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the `has_delete_permission()` method:

```
from django.contrib.admin import helpers

class SliderContentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    min_objects = 1

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj):
        queryset = self.model.objects.all()

        # If we're running the bulk delete action, estimate the number
        # of objects after we delete the selected items
        selected = request.POST.getlist(helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME)
        if selected:
            queryset = queryset.exclude(pk__in=selected)

        if queryset.count() <= self.min_objects:
            message = 'There should be at least {} object(s) left.'
            self.message_user(request, message.format(self.min_objects))
            return False

        return super(SliderContentAdmin, self).has_delete_permission(request, obj)
```

Comment: That's what I'm after, it works for the last entry. It doesn't work on bulk delete, I'm thinking I can modify this if I can count the selected items but I don't know what I would use?

Comment: Does this code work on ```delete_model```? I guess this is not a permission issue, so overriding ```has_delete_permission``` may not be the better way to solve the problem

Comment: @DaniloFreitas As far as I know, the `has_delete_permission()` is called both when you try to delete a single model and before the bulk deletion action. And these are the ways of deleting @Ozzy is concerned about. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What I want to say is that ```has_delete_permission``` should be used **only** to check permission issues. But I don't know if there's a better way to do that. @Ozzy could you try this code on ```delete_model``` and tell us if it works? If it doesn't work, I guess @AlexMorozov answer is the better way to do that.

Comment: @DaniloFreitas, `delete_model()` isn't called on a bulk delete via action. And from my perspective, the `has_delete_permission()` is the exact and the best place for this kind of functionality. What it does is determines if the user has a pemission to delete object(s). It's not only about the actual `User.permissions` matching, the permission is a broad term and could be used to check the number of remaining records, a user registration date, a phase of the Moon, virtually anything. So I believe we're in the right place :).

Comment: @AlexMorozov I've tried your answer but its errors with 'pop() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)' I removed None just to see but then it errors stating an integer is required for the same line?

Comment: @Ozzy, sorry, my mistake. That line is redundant, I've removed it in the example. Please, try out the current version.

Comment: @AlexMorozov I guess you're right, then. I forgot about the bulk delete. Thanks for letting it clear for me

Comment: @AlexMorozov I did try it without that line but I found it didn't work, I was trying to select the second to last entry. Altering if queryset.count() <= self.min_objects: to if queryset.count() < self.min_objects: sorted this issue. Thanks for your help